# Why is the object type```TextStream``` set to nothing?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2019

When the program runs, it goes through `function Initialize` without issues. When `function WriteString` is called, log's value has changed to "Nothing". On the `Retry`, when `Call Initialize` runs, `Set log = FSO.OpenTextFile(sLogPath & sLogName, 2, 0)` returns Error 70.

```
Option Explicit
Public log As TextStream

Function Initialize()
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim sLogName As String
    Dim sLogPath As String
    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
    'Call Terminate
    sLogPath = "C:\Users\" & UserName & "\Documents\VbaLog"
    sLogName = "\progressLog.txt"
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(sLogPath) Then
        MkDir sLogPath
    End If
Retry:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    On Error GoTo eError
    If Dir(sLogPath & sLogName) <> "" Then
        Set log = FSO.OpenTextFile(sLogPath & sLogName, 2, 0)
    Else
        Set log = FSO.CreateTextFile(sLogPath & sLogName, False)
    End If
    Exit Function
    Set FSO = Nothing
    Exit Function
eError:
    If Err.Number = 70 Then
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "attrib -r " & sLogPath
    End If
    GoTo Retry
End Function

Function WriteString(argument As String)
Retry:
    If Not log Is Nothing Then
        log.WriteLine Now & ": " & argument
    Else
        Call Initialize
        GoTo Retry
    End If
End Function

Function Terminate()
    If Not log Is Nothing Then
        log.Close
    Else
        Set log = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

The LogPath folder's property attribute is set to Read-Only. I uncheck that box but, it keeps coming back. I've even disabled inheritance for that folder and yet, nothing I do to the folder permantely uncheck the read-only attribute

Comment: Is the Read-only attribute also set for the log file?

Comment: Try a different folder, not under c:\users. It might be some synchronizing issues.

Comment: @TimWilliams, the file doesn't have the attribute, only the parent folder

Comment: @Sam, changed the path to: ```sLogPath = "C:\Temp\VbaLog"``` & same results :(